# Initial DT Processing has a slow network request

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server, dt

the "Processing..." step of a [DT](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) in my Shiny App takes a long time as soon as the app does not run locally on my PC, but on a shiny server.
I profiled the app using profvis (remotely on the server), but the " DT::renderDataTable" step takes only ~400ms (approx. 2000 rows).

Chrome however shows a "Network request step" that takes ~15secs:

[image: Chrome Profiling Screenshot]

Info from the Chrome performance analysis:

- Network request URL
  /session/d229229…/dataobj/dataTableOut?w=&nonce=ce39...
- Duration 15.89 s
- Request Method POST
- Priority High
- Mime Type application/json
- Encoded Data 1.7 KB
- Decoded Body 5.2 KB
- Initiator jquery.min.js:2

What is causing this delay?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem:

The root cause why the shiny server behaved differently from my local version was the number of available cpu cores.
Some extensive background request are handled by the future/promises packages in my shiny app. Due to a bottleneck of cores on the remote server, these requests where blocking the DT processing and thus the network request to load the DT took so long.